# How to prevent kitchen backsplash tiles from countertop to ceiling from cracking?

Tags: walls, kitchens, tile

## Context

I am planning to install porcelain herringbone tiles on my kitchen walls. Countertop to ceiling. I want to make sure the tiles dont crack with time and structure movement.

- The structural wall is an exterior wall.
- The tiles will be installed on a sister wall that we built to hide the drain on the structural wall. The two walls (structural/bearing and sister partition wall) are fixed together.
- The tiles will go from countertop to ceiling about 5.5 ft tall by 10ft wide.

## Question

- What technique to use to prevent tiles from cracking under normal temperature and humidity stud structure movement?
- What type of mortar to use?
- Any layer/mesh/pad (ie reinforcement) to insert in the mortar to control for movement?

Comment: You have multiple questions in one here. While related, on the whole they'd require a veritable guidebook to tiling in an answer. I suggest doing some reading on standard practices. Note that small tiles on walls rarely crack. It's the _grout_ that might crack, but that's not difficult to prevent with proper backing. 1/2" cement board or CDX plywood are common. Your tile store can tell you what mortar to use, depending on what they stock.

Comment: Epoxy grout is hard to work with but unbeatable for stain resistance, water proofing and adds structure.  If DIYing watch HomeRenovision youtube - dishsoap tiles before grout for easier cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you leave a 1/16-1/8" gap at the counter and ceiling to caulk instead of filling with grout. You can fill with backer rod when grouting to prevent filling it up or just scrape it out before it hardens.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing backsplashes for decades.  Sometimes with unusual things that the homeowner wants for unknown reasons.

My "go to" materials are 1/2" cement board and [AcrylPro](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-AcrylPro-1-Gal-Ceramic-Tile-Adhesive-ARL40001/100015587?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD-71700000110012104-58700008378060400-92700076247463652&gclid=CjwKCAjw1YCkBhAOEiwA5aN4AQOzpe8I6ZTewqoihcIApdMuh_7GGzY80VSABH6ioRvlZtGSxgikmxoCnxkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) mastic.

Never had issues with cracks or grout falling out.  The cement board is very stable and the AcrylPro mastic dries white and has a slight bit of give to it.
It's the mastic I would use for most any backsplash other than clear glass.

Comment: Thanks! What do you do if drywall is already installed and cement board is not an option?

Comment: I have done plenty of tiling over just drywall using the AcrylPro with excellent results.

Comment: *"drywall is already installed and cement board is not an option"* Drywall can be ripped out and replaced with cementboard. Neither one costs much of anything compared to the cost of porcelain tiles, but cementboard is a much better base for that expensive and labor-intensive surface finish. But sure, save the price of pizza if you like.

Comment: @Max why is CBU not an option?

Comment: Hi @Ecnerwal - I agree that cement-board is a better surface, usually required in wet environment such as showers, but it is not a required surface for dry environment for tiles application.     For your reference - International Building Code restricts the use of gypsum drywall, including water-resistant gypsum drywall, in wet areas such as showers and tub surrounds. In these applications, the gypsum drywall should be removed and replaced with a cement-board for tiles application. Bare gypsum drywall is a suitable substrate in all dry, interior applications.

Comment: I didn't say code doesn't accept it. Code minimum is to try to keep slumlords honest. I said it's an inferior substrate that saves very little money on the overall tile project and thus puts the expensive part of the project on an inferior base. Enjoy your pizza.